# Can't render line breaks in Rails with simple_format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm aware that in order to render \r\n I need to use simple_format, however it doesn't work on my posts that I migrated from WordPress. I tried many solutions including regex to replace \r\n with break tags, but it didn't help either. I still see on the screen all the line breaks printed out as text and not rendered. 
Here is what I tried:

```
<%= simple_format(@post.body) %> 
<%= simple_format(@post.body.gsub(/(?:\n\r?|\r\n?)/, '<br>')) %>
```

If I just do something like below it will work.

```
<%= simple_format "<h1>Briefed while smartwatch firm Pebble lays off 25% of its staff</h1> -\r\n\r\n \r\n <p>hello</p>" %>
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it using an SQL query:

```
UPDATE posts SET body = REPLACE(body, '\r\n', '<br>');
```

Don't know why Rails gsub didn't work.

Edit:
Looks like my regex was wrong. This solves it too:

```
<%= simple_format(@post.body.gsub(/\\r\\n/, "\n")) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following, it should works for you, I have tested, its working

```
> "\n\r".gsub(/[\r\n]+/, '<br>') => "<br>" 
> "\r\n".gsub(/[\r\n]+/, '<br>') => "<br>"
```

In your case

```
 (@post.body.gsub(/[\r\n]+/, '<br>')
```

Comment: whats your ruby version?

Comment: 2.3. It has nothing to do with that. The problem was that I migrated the posts from a MySQL DB to Postgres DB and it changed the format of the content. Solution is similar to your I just needed an extra slash